# Apache Solr indexing SQL data

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Is there any way to continue the indexing of a large SQL dataset from where we left in Apache Solr using data import handler

**Example:**
like I stopped indexing at row 1000 after extracting a data and processing completed I stopped my Solr and indexes were updated, now I want to continue from there.

How to do that?

This is my `data-config.xml`:

```
<entity name="id" query="select movie_id as 'id',title, genres from movies;">
    <field column="title" name="movie_name"/>
    <field column="genres" name="genres"/>
    <entity name="links_id" query="select imdb_id,tmdb_id from links where movie_id=${id.id};">
        <field name="imdb_id" column="imdb_id" />
        <field name="tmdb_id" column="tmdb_id" />
    </entity>
    <entity name="movie_rating" query="select avg(rating),count(*) from ratings where movie_id=${id.id};">
        <field column="avg(rating)" name="avg_rating"/>
        <field column="count(*)" name="total_users_rated"/>
    </entity>
</entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LIMIT statement in the SQL in your DIH configuration. There is no automagic way to do this in Solr, as Solr can't know how many rows were indexed, and whether the SQL database has changed between restarting the indexing process.

You might also be able to submit parameters to the import process through the URL when calling the full-import and using the `${}` syntax in the configuration file to reference that value (`start_at=1000` or something similar). But for a one or two-off, just use the hardcoded value in the DIH configuration file.

Comment: Actually I thought of doing this but the problem is if I will start reindexing with full import it will delete the previous indexed file.

Comment: You can use the deltaImport to provide an alternative query - but even better, add `clean=false` to the URL: `clean : (default 'true'). Tells whether to clean up the index before the indexing is started.`